# I have a set of dates in 6 columns in an excel sheet. How do I find the common dates in all these 6 columns?

Tags: excel, ms-office, excel-2016

I have six columns with dates (in the same format). There are some common dates in each of these columns. I tried using the 'duplicate' option in conditional formatting, but this is giving all the values the are common in any of the six columns. I need to find the dates that are common in all the six columns.

Comment: You can use sumproduct with if to identify the common column. Please provide example for your question. you should be able to get the right answer

Answer (score 0):

With data like:

[image]

This short macro:

```
Sub Kommon()
    Dim i As Long, N As Long, j As Long, d As Date, IsGood As Boolean
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
    For i = 1 To N
        d = Cells(i, 1).Value
        IsGood = True
            For j = 2 To 6
                If .CountIf(Range(Cells(1, j), Cells(Rows.Count, j)), d) = 0 Then
                    IsGood = False
                End If
            Next j
        If IsGood Then
            Cells(i, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 27
        End If
    Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

loops down a single column and checks the other five columns:

[image]

So ***8/1/2005*** is present in all six columns.